# Update CC info of Braintree in PHP

Tags: php, braintree

I am trying to update CC info of braintree but function provided in docs is not working . and I am unable to find out the reason.

Here is my function :

```
public function updateCC(){

        $fname      =   $this->input->get_post('fname');
        $lname      =   $this->input->get_post('lname');
        $expirationYear   =   $this->input->get_post('expirationYear');
        $expirationMonth   =   $this->input->get_post('expirationMonth');
        $cardholderName =   $this->input->get_post('cardholderName');
        $cvv        =   $this->input->get_post('cvv');
        $cc_no      =   $this->input->get_post('cc_no');

        $token      =   $this->input->get_post('token');
        $BTCustomerID   =   $this->input->get_post('BTCustomerID ');


     $result = Braintree_Customer::update(
                $BTCustomerID,
                (
            'firstName' => $fname,
            'lastName' => $lname,
            'creditCard' => (
                      'paymentMethodNonce' => 'fake-valid-nonce',

                'options' => (
             'updateExistingToken' => $token,
                  'verifyCard' => true

                )
             )           
        ));

    echo json_encode(array('error'=>-1));
 }
```

Due to this code my application is crashing .

```
 $result = Braintree_Customer::update(
            $BTCustomerID,
            (
        'firstName' => $fname,
        'lastName' => $lname,
        'creditCard' => (
                  'paymentMethodNonce' => 'fake-valid-nonce',
            'options' => (
         'updateExistingToken' => $token,
              'verifyCard' => true,

            )
         )           
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m a developer at Braintree. In your call to `Braintree_Customer::update()`, `paymentMethodNonce` must be passed inside of `creditCard` at the same level as `options`. In your code you are passing the it inside of `options`. See [this code example](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/reference/request/customer/update#update-customer-and-existing-credit-card) for reference.

Comment: Can you please explain what is payment method nonce ? I read documents but it didn't  clear to me.

Comment: @ShumailaHameedKhan payment method nonce is string returned client side SDK to represent a `payment method`. When you enter you CC card details and submits, payment method nonce generated automatically by client sdk. We sent payment method nonce to server to create the transaction. We can generate the payment method token by using the payment method nonce.

Comment: In your code, you must replace `fake-valid-nonce` with the actual nonce we pass back to your client. See [our docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/start/hello-server#receive-a-payment-method-nonce-from-your-client) for more information, and please reach out to support for further help understanding payment method nonces. https://support.braintreepayments.com